# Spark Cassandra connector - using IN for filtering with dynamic data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

Let's assume that I have an `RDD` with items of type

```
case class Foo(name: String, nums: Seq[Int])
```

and a table `my_schema.foo` in `Cassandra` with a partitioning key composed of `name` and `num` columns

Now, I'd like to fetch for each element in the input RDD all corresponding rows, i.e. something like:

```
SELECT * from my_schema.foo where name = :name and num IN :nums
```

I've tried the following approaches:

1. use the `joinWithCassandraTable` extension: `rdd.joinWithCassandraTable("my_schema", "foo").on(SomeColumns("name"))` but I don't know how I could specify the `IN` constraint
2. For each element of the input RDD issue a separate query (within a `map` function). This does not work, as the spark context is not serializable and cannot be passed into the `map`
3. Flatmap the input RDD to generate a separate item `(name, num)` for each `num` in `nums`. This will work, but it will probably be way less efficient than using an `IN` clause.

What would be a proper way of solving this problem?